# How save data on user's client cache

Tags: php, cache

Is there a way to cache data on user's browser. I need to save a object that depend from user. I used wp_cache_set, but I notice that it expire after one request. Is there a way to save this data for each request?

Comment: How are you using `wp_cache_set()` right now? You may want to use the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) instead if you want to be sure that your data is cached.

Comment: @janh Yes, I'm using wp_cache_set now. But transient create an option temporary on DB, so if two user logged in, both share the same option. In that way, data cache on server, not on user's browser.

Comment: Either add a unique identifier to the cache key, or maybe use PHP sessions?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_cache_*` methods are cached in either php memory or an object cache ( if available ) . It will never be available to be saved in the browser.

If you want to save it on the browser side, you'll need to use JavaScript. Local or Session storage are great for that https://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage